# Getting Text Input in Google Actions(recent version)

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

How to get user input from actions SDK(recent version).
In the previous version, we just use text intent like the example

```
app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', async (conv, input) => {
   console.log('input', input)
})
```

I want to get user input as we do get in the previous version but the previous version is deprecating.
How to get user input from the action builder?

In recent version they are providing intents, scenes, types etcc...

Answer (score 3):

The [custom NLU sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-custom-nlu-nodejs/) provides an example of sending the user's full text to your webhook to process.

It is accomplished through a simple [user_utterance intent](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-custom-nlu-nodejs/blob/master/sdk/custom/intents/user_utterance.yaml) that accepts [freeText](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-custom-nlu-nodejs/blob/master/sdk/custom/types/any.yaml) and then [calls a webhook](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-custom-nlu-nodejs/blob/master/sdk/custom/scenes/Main.yaml).

Then your webhook can handle the intent's parameter:

```js
app.handle('doAny', (conv) => {
    const any = conv.intent.params.any.original;
    conv.add(`You said ${any}.`);
});
```

Comment: Thankyou @Nick Felker. And may I know why they are provided intents, scenes, and types we have already Dialogflow if we want NLP. Please tell me if you know

Comment: Actions Builder is orthogonal to Dialogflow. You can use either one for NLP.